# Disable autosave in Office 2019 when logged into OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive

[MS Community Question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/disable-autosave-in-office-2019-when-logged-into/d63249ff-7bca-4d9c-a2af-9b09b68039c9)

I have Office 2019, as well as a OneDrive account, and Office 365 on some machines..

When I use Excel 365 and save to OneDrive it defaults to autosave, however I can use the quick access toggle to disable autosave... reasonable..

When I use Excel 2019 (my pref) and save locally, I dont have access to autosave BUT when I save file to OneDrive, autosave is forced upon me and I cannot disable any way I have found... no toggle, no option under save, nothing....

What am I missing.. this drives me crazy when I accidentally delete something or make a change and have it autosaved.... and only way to reverse is to close file and go thru OneDrive file versions as I can't even undo... crazy

In Office 2021 there is an option to disable this behavior:

[image]

Hoping someone has an idea?

Comment: The option you mention is in Word but not Excel or PowerPoint 2021 for some reason. MS has an article that might help; it references a group policy setting but it's often possible to figure out what registry setting that makes. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-it-administrators-should-know-about-autosave-88e0f80f-e5ea-441b-9c5a-259f08490ae7

Comment: I have to ask. Why do you have 3 different versions of Office installed? When installing a single version, the current Office 365 build, would resolve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

There is a [Microsoft Community post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/disable-autosave-in-office-2019-when-logged-into/d63249ff-7bca-4d9c-a2af-9b09b68039c9) addressing this issue.  (Actually, the question here is repeated verbatim from that post, suggesting you also asked there, so this is probably not the answer you are looking for.)

In case it is helpful to others, they said you can go to the File > Options > Save and locate the option called "Save to computer by default".

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately, that dialog lets  you control where Auto-Recovered files are saved; Auto-Recover isn't the same as Auto-Save.

Comment: This answer doesn’t answer the author’s question. You should [edit] it and address that fact.